# How to set a session for a user while using devise gem

Tags: devise

Does anyone know how to handle the session object manually?
I know devise stores it in the database, but there must be a way to set the session manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `warden.set_user(resource, :scope => scope)`

This is an example to test that a user can only see contracts to which he has access. (has_role! and has_no_role! is from acl9 - great gem to manage access control)

```
describe "GET index (logged in)" do
    it "@contracts contains only contracts on which user has admin role" do
        coA = Factory.create(:contract,:contract_name => "contract_A" )
        coB = Factory.create(:contract,:contract_name => "contract_B" )
        userA = Factory.create(:user, :username => "userA")
        userA.has_role! :admin, coA
        userA.has_no_role! coB
        warden.set_user(userA, :scope => "user")
        get :index, :locale => "fr"
        assigns(:contracts).should eq([coA])
    end
end
```

Comment: If we have to check if user is logged in or not then what to do?

Comment: (This is actually a reply to Antoine's answer, but I don't see how to reply to it!)

Where is 'warden' defined?

Comment: warden is something devise uses, so anywhere you can do devise things, you SHOULD be able to do warden things